# Include vars in role tasks

Tags: ansible

In a role, I am trying to load some variables from another role. (If that role was included in the current play, the variables would be accessible, but it's not so they're not.)

So I tried this:

```
- include_vars: ../../another_role/defaults/main.yml
```

But it doesn't work, no error but the variables are still undefined.
So I tried to be smart and symlink the file to `vars/another_role_defaults.yml` in the role where I want to use the vars and then include it like this:

```
- include_vars: another_role_defaults.yml
```

Same result, no error (why doesn't it throw an error if the file cannot be found??) but variables are still undefined. I tried this as well, for good measure, but still no cigar.

```
- include_vars: ../vars/another_role_defaults.yml
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It was my own fault in the end... I tested this by using the `debug` module and `tags` like this:

```
- include_vars: ../../another_role/defaults/main.yml

- debug: msg={{ variable }}
  tags: foo
```

and then executing the playbook like this:

```
  ansible-playbook -vvvv playbook.yml --tags foo
```

Once I left out the tags, it works (of course). The problem was that I should have added the tags to the `include_vars` command as well like this:

```
- include_vars: ../../another_role/defaults/main.yml
  tags: foo

- debug: msg={{ variable }}
  tags: foo
```

Comment: Great "feature". Just spent half an hour on this. Thanks for posting the response.

Comment: Half an hour not half of day )

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution did not work in my case in case a file is imported from another role. A slightly modified approach via special variable which worked for me:

```
- include_vars: "{{ role_path }}/../another_role/defaults/main.yml"
  tags: foo
```

[role_path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) - The path to the dir of the currently running role

Answer (score 2):

As of ansible-core 2.11 you can do this:

```yaml
- include_vars: ../../nrpe/vars/standard_nrpe_checks.yml
  name: standard_nrpe_checks
- debug:
    msg: "{{ standard_nrpe_checks }}"
```

To get the same result you can also use `set_fact` with the lookup plugin.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', '../../nrpe/vars/standard_nrpe_checks.yml') }}"
```

I wanted to mention if you're using collections and distributing a playbook you can use

```
playbooks
  |_vars/
    |_standard_nrpe_checks.yml
```

In this instance I'm now able to share vars from within a collection and since it's in the lookup path I don't need to specify it relatively. I.e. instead of having a list be an nrpe role default read it in for both roles and maintain it in one place.

```yaml
- include_vars: standard_nrpe_checks.yml
  name: standard_nrpe_checks
- debug:
    msg: "{{ standard_nrpe_checks }}"
```

```
TASK [namespace.my_collection.icinga : debug] *******************************************
ok: [hostname] =>
  msg: |-
    standard_nrpe_checks:
      check_users:
        script: check_users
```